# Construct List<T> from Enumeration<? extends T>

Tags: java, templates

How can I construct a `List<T>` from a `Enumeration<? extends T>`?

The best way I have found is this

```
Enumeration<? extends T> toBeConverted;
List<T> = new ArrayList<>(Collections.list(toBeConverted));
```

But that creates a two `List` (one in the `Collections.list` method, and other in the constructor of `ArrayList`). Is there any way to avoid that temporary copy?

(Other solution would be:

```
List<T> list = new ArrayList<T>;
while (toBeConverted.hasMoreElements) { list.add(toBeConverted.nextElement()); }
```

but I think that is too verbose.... I'd like a solution with constructors if possible)

Answer (score 0):

Method `Collections.list` make new ArrayList.

```
public static <T> ArrayList<T> list(Enumeration<T> e) {
    ArrayList<T> l = new ArrayList<>();
    while (e.hasMoreElements())
        l.add(e.nextElement());
    return l;
}
```

You can call just `Collections.list` method without constructor.

```
Enumeration<? extends T> toBeConverted;
List<T> = (List<T>) Collections.list(toBeConverted);
```

Comment: That is obiously the first I tried, but `List<T> = Collections.list(toBeConverted);` doesn't compile.

Comment: Is that cast `(List <T>)` always safe? Or could it throw a `ClassCastException`?

Comment: It won't throw a `ClassCastException`, because of type erasure.

Comment: List<? extends T> cast to List<T> should be always safe. I can't found proof but in JDK cast like this used many times.

Comment: Well, except that it sabotages the compiler's efforts to keep you from putting the wrong type of object in the list.  In general, a `List<? extends T>` should NOT be a `List<T>`, so it's not safe at compile time.  But at run time, the generics go away; so if you can tell the compiler to ignore your error, things will probably work out OK in the end.